# custom form validation based on type selection using html JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, developer-tools, react-fullstack

I have a one form divided in to two parts. I want validation after page load.

First show only three field and I want the two field validated so if user clicks without entering data in the two fields,then show the error like my screenshot. This works perfectly in my js code

[image]

When I am selecting rent or sell in the first field, if I choose sell, then the other field shows property type residential and commercial and if I selected residential then third field shows property sub type bungalow, apartment, land.
For example I selected property residential and then property type show apartment and after selecting residential shows lots of field like my screenshot.

[image]
After I show these field I am facing error look below screenshot I am highlighting field

[image]

When i select "ready to move" then I show one field "age of property" and I want if I selected "ready to move" then the required age of property field is activated and if I select "under construction" then hide "age of property" and automatically remove required field from age of property

When showing the "field possession date" then required possession date looks like my screenshot mentioned

[image]

[image]

The JavaScript code is working when I selected ready to move and show the age of property and filling all the field with age property and then click submit button the form is submitted successfully

However if I selected under construction and filling the all required field then submit button not working

```js
const propertyForm = document.getElementById("propertyForm");
const propertyCategory = document.getElementById("property_cat");
const residentialFields = document.getElementById("R-Property");
const commercialFields = document.getElementById("C-Property");
const queryonSelect = document.getElementById("queryon");
const propertySubTypeSelect = document.getElementById("Residentialproperty");
const propertyAvailabilitySelect = document.getElementById("PropertyAvailability");
const propertyAgeInput = document.getElementById("PropertyAge");
const possessionDateInput = document.getElementById("possessionyear");

function handleCategoryChange() {
  if (propertyCategory.value === "Residential") {
    residentialFields.style.display = "block";
    commercialFields.style.display = "none";
  } else if (propertyCategory.value === "Commercial") {
    residentialFields.style.display = "none";
    commercialFields.style.display = "block";
  }
}

// Set default category type and handle the change
propertyCategory.addEventListener("change", handleCategoryChange);

// Call the handleCategoryChange function on page load
window.addEventListener("load", handleCategoryChange);

propertyForm.addEventListener("submit", function(event) {
  let hasError = false; // Flag to track if there's any error

  if (propertyCategory.value === "Residential") {
    // Validation for residential fields
    const R_city = document.getElementById("R_city_r");
    const R_Locality = document.getElementById("R_Locality_r");
    const ApartmentName = document.getElementById("ApartmentName");
    const Bedrooms = document.getElementById("bedrooms");
    const Bathrooms = document.getElementById("bathrooms");
    const Balcony = document.getElementById("Balcony");
    const Superbuiltuparea_r = document.getElementById("superbuiltuparea-r");
    const Carpetsize_r = document.getElementById("carpetsize-r");
    const PropertyAvailability = document.getElementById("PropertyAvailability");
    const PropertyAge = document.getElementById("PropertyAge");
    const Expectedprice_r = document.getElementById("expectedprice-r");
    const Brokeroption = document.getElementById("brokeroption");
    const Propertydisc_r = document.getElementById("Propertydisc_r");

    // Check if propertyAvailability is 'Ready to Move'
    const isReadyToMove = PropertyAvailability.value === "Ready to Move";

    // Clear the "Possession Year" validation if "Ready to Move" is selected
    if (isReadyToMove) {
      clearError("R_possession_error");
      possessionDateInput.removeAttribute("required");
    } else {
      possessionDateInput.setAttribute("required", "required");
    }

    // Add validations for other residential fields
    if (R_city.value.trim() === "") {
      setError("R_city_error", "City is required.");
      hasError = true;
    } else {
      clearError("R_city_error");
    }
    if (R_Locality.value.trim() === "") {
      setError("R_Locality_error", "Locality is required.");
      hasError = true;
    } else {
      clearError("R_Locality_error");
    }
    if (ApartmentName.value.trim() === "") {
      setError("R_society_error", "Society name is required.");
      hasError = true;
    } else {
      clearError("R_society_error");
    }

    // Add more validations for other residential fields here.

    if (!isReadyToMove) {
      // If property is 'Under Construction', validate Property Age
      if (PropertyAge.value.trim() === "") {
        setError("R_Pro_Age_error", "Property Age is required.");
        hasError = true;
        propertyAgeInput.setAttribute("required", "required"); // Add "required" attribute back
      } else {
        clearError("R_Pro_Age_error");
        propertyAgeInput.removeAttribute("required"); // Remove "required" attribute
      }

      possessionDateInput.setAttribute("required", "required");
    }
  } else if (propertyCategory.value === "Commercial") {
    // Validation for commercial fields
    const Kindofoffice = document.getElementById("Kindofoffice");
    const C_city_name = document.getElementById("C_city_name");
    const C_projectname = document.getElementById("C_projectname");
    const C_Localtiy = document.getElementById("C_Localtiy");
    const Locatedinside = document.getElementById("Locatedinside");
    const Zonetype = document.getElementById("Zonetype");
    const Superbuiltuparea_c = document.getElementById("Superbuiltuparea_c");
    const Carpetsize_c = document.getElementById("Carpetsize_c");
    const Ominsit = document.getElementById("Ominsit");
    const Ocabins = document.getElementById("Ocabins");
    const Omeetroom = document.getElementById("Omeetroom");
    const OWashingroom = document.getElementById("OWashingroom");
    const C_privatewashroom = document.getElementById("C_privatewashroom");
    const C_conferenceroom = document.getElementById("C_conferenceroom");
    const C_Receptionarea = document.getElementById("C_Receptionarea");
    const C_PantryType = document.getElementById("C_PantryType");
    const Radio1 = document.getElementById("radio1");
    const Totalfloor = document.getElementById("Totalfloor");
    const Lifts = document.getElementById("lifts");
    const Parking = document.getElementById("parking");
    const CommercialAvailablity = document.getElementById("CommercialAvailablity");
    const PropertyAgec = document.getElementById("PropertyAgec");
    const Cpossessionyears = document.getElementById("Cpossessionyears");
    const Radioowner3 = document.getElementById("radioowner3");
    const Expectedprice_c = document.getElementById("expectedprice-c");
    const Bookingamntc = document.getElementById("Bookingamntc");
    const Brokeragecoyes = document.getElementById("brokeragecoyes");
    const Propertydiscc = document.getElementById("propertydiscc");

    // Check if propertyAvailability is 'Ready to Move'
    const isReadyToMove = CommercialAvailablity.value === "Ready to Move";

    // Clear the "Property Age" validation if "Ready to Move" is selected
    if (isReadyToMove) {
      clearError("PropertyAgec_error");
      propertyAgeInput.removeAttribute("required");
    } else {
      propertyAgeInput.setAttribute("required", "required");
    }

    // Add validations for other commercial fields
    // ...

    if (Kindofoffice.value === "") {
      setError("Kindofoffice_error", "Property looking option is required.");
      hasError = true;
    } else {
      clearError("Kindofoffice_error");
    }

    // Add more validations for other commercial fields here.

    if (!isReadyToMove) {
      // If property is 'Under Construction', validate Possession Date
      if (Cpossessionyears.value.trim() === "") {
        setError("Cpossessionyears_error", "Please select possession date.");
        hasError = true;
        possessionDateInput.setAttribute("required", "required"); // Add "required" attribute back
      } else {
        clearError("Cpossessionyears_error");
        possessionDateInput.removeAttribute("required"); // Remove "required" attribute
      }

      propertyAgeInput.setAttribute("required", "required");
    }
  }

  // Add validations for other common fields

  // Validate the "Property Looking For" select
  if (queryonSelect.value === "") {
    setError("residential-looking", "Please select an option.");
    hasError = true;
  } else {
    clearError("residential-looking");
  }

  // Validate the "Property Sub Type" select
  if (propertySubTypeSelect.value === "") {
    setError("property_sub_type", "Please choose a type.");
    hasError = true;
  } else {
    clearError("property_sub_type");
  }

  // If there are no errors, the form will be submitted.
  if (hasError) {
    event.preventDefault(); // Prevent form submission for errors
  }
});

// Helper function to set error message
function setError(id, message) {
  const errorElement = document.getElementById(id);
  errorElement.textContent = message;
  errorElement.style.color = "red";
}

// Helper function to clear error message
function clearError(id) {
  const errorElement = document.getElementById(id);
  errorElement.textContent = "";
}
```

```html
<form class="contact_form" name="contact_form" action="include/listing_store.php" method="post" novalidate enctype="multipart/form-data" id="propertyForm">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <div class="ui_kit_select_search add_new_property mb30">
        <select class="selectpicker" data-width="100%" id="queryon" name="property_looking">
          <option value="" selected disabled>Property Looking For</option>
          <option data-tokens="rent">Rent</option>
          <option data-tokens="sell">Sell</option>
        </select>
        <p class="error property_looking" id="residential-looking"></p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <div class="ui_kit_select_search add_new_property mb30">
        <select class="selectpicker" data-width="100%" id='property_cat' name='property_cat' onchange='showcommercial()'>
          <option value="" selected disabled>Property Category</option>
          <option value="Residential">Residential</option>
          <option value="Commercial">Commercial</option>
        </select>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <div class="ui_kit_select_search add_new_property mb30">
        <select class="sagar" data-width="100%" id="Residentialproperty" name="property_sub_type">
          <option Value='' selected disabled hidden>Choose Type</option>
        </select>
        <p class="error property_sub_type" id="property_sub_type"></p>
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- main Residential code Start -->
    <div class="ResidentialProperty" id="R-Property">
      <div class="col-lg-12">
        <div class="new_property_form" id="location">
          <h4 class="title mb30">Location</h4>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4">
              <div class="ui_kit_select_search add_new_property mb30">
                <select class="selectpicker" data-live-search="true" data-width="100%" id="R_city_r" name="R_city">
                  <option value="" selected disabled>Locality / City</option>
                  <option data-tokens="Ahmedabad">Ahmedabad</option>
                </select>
                <p class="error R_city" id="R_city_error"></p>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
              <div class="form-group mb30">
                <input class="form-control form_control" type="text" id="R_Locality_r" name="R_Locality" placeholder="Locality">
                <p class="error R_Locality" id="R_Locality_error"></p>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
              <div class="form-group mb30">
                <input class="form-control form_control" type="text" id="ApartmentName" name="R_society" placeholder="Appartment/Society">
                <p class="error R_society" id="R_society_error"></p>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
              <div class="form-group mb30">
                <input class="form-control form_control" type="text" id="HouseNumber" name="R_H_number" placeholder="House Number" id="HouseNumber">
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-12">
        <div class="new_property_form">
          <h4 class="title mb30">Property Details</h4>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4">
              <div class="form-group mb30">
                <input class="form-control form_control" type="text" id="bedrooms" name="R_Bedroom" placeholder="No Of Bedrooms">
                <p class="error R_Bedroom" id="R_Bedroom_error"></p>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
              <div class="form-group mb30">
                <input class="form-control form_control" type="text" id="bathrooms" name="R_Bathroom" placeholder="Number Of Bathrooms">
                <p class="error R_Bathroom" id="R_Bathroom_error"></p>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
              <div class="form-group mb30">
                <input class="form-control form_control" type="text" id="Balcony" name="R_Balcony" placeholder="Number Of Balconies">
                <p class="error R_Balcony" id="R_Balcony_error"></p>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
              <div class="ui_kit_select_search add_new_property mb30">
                <div class="form-group mb30">
                  <input class="form-control form_control" type="number" id="superbuiltuparea-r" name="R_Sup_Build" placeholder="Super Built-Up Area">
                  <select id="measuringunits" name="R_Super_Build_Meas_unit">
                    <option value="sqft">sq.ft</option>
                    <option value="sqyards">sq.yards</option>
                    <option value="sqm">sq.m</option>
                    <option value="acres">acres</option>
                    <option value="marla">marla</option>
                    <option value="cents">cents</option>
                  </select>
                  <p class="error R_Sup_Build" id="R_Sup_Build_error"></p>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-4">
              <div class="ui_kit_select_search add_new_property mb30">
                <div class="form-group mb30">
                  <input class="form-control form_control" type="text" id="carpetsize-r" name="R_Carpet" placeholder="Carpet Size">
                  <select id="measuringunits" name="R_Carpet_Meas_unit">
                    <option value="sqft">sq.ft</option>
                    <option value="sqyards">sq.yards</option>
                    <option value="sqm">sq.m</option>
                    <option value="acres">acres</option>
                    <option value="marla">marla</option>
                    <option value="cents">cents</option>
                  </select>
                  <p class="error R_Carpet" id="R_Carpet_error"></p>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-4">
              <div class="ui_kit_select_search add_new_property mb30">
                <select class="selectpicker show-tick" data-width="100%" id="otherrooms" name="R_Other_Rooms[]" multiple="multiple">
                  <option value="" selected disabled>Other rooms</option>
                  <option value="Pooja Room">Pooja Room</option>
                  <option value="Study Room">Study Room</option>
                  <option value="Store Room">Store Room</option>
                </select>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-4">
              <div class="ui_kit_select_search add_new_property mb30">
                <select class="selectpicker" data-width="100%" id="furnishing" name="R_Furnished">
                  <option value="furnished">Furnished</option>
                  <option value="semiFurnished">Semi-Furnished</option>
                  <option value="unfurnished">Un-Furnished</option>
                </select>
                <p class="error R_Furnished" id="R_Furnished"></p>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-4">
              <div class="form-group mb30">
                <input class="form-control form_control" type="number" id="reservedparks" name="R_R_Parking" placeholder="Reserved Parking">
                <p class="error R_R_Parking" id="R_R_Parking"></p>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
              <div class="form-group mb30">
                <input class="form-control form_control" type="number" id='openparks' name='R_O_Parking' placeholder="Open Parking">
              </div>
            </div>
            <!-- floor Details -->
            <div class="col-md-4">
              <div class="form-group mb30">
                <input class="form-control form_control" type="number" id='rtotalfloor' name='R_Total_Floor' placeholder="Total Floor" oninput="generateOptions()">
                <p class="error rtotalfloor" id="rtotalfloor"></p>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-4" id="rfloornumber">
              <div class="ui_kit_select_search add_new_property mb30" id="floornumberoption">
                <select class="form-control" id="propertyfloornumber" data-width="100%" name="R_Floor_Number" style="padding-top: 18px;">
                </select>
                <p class="error propertyfloornumber" id="propertyfloornumber"></p>
              </div>
            </div>

            <!-- floor details end -->
            <div class="col-md-4">
              <div class="ui_kit_select_search add_new_property mb30">
                <select class="selectpicker" data-width="100%" id="PropertyAvailability" name="R_Ready_to_Moove">
                  <option value="" disabled selected hidden>Ready to Move / Underconstruction</option>
                  <option value='Ready to Move'>Ready to Move</option>
                  <option value='Under Construction'>Under Construction</option>
                </select>
                <p class="error R_Ready_to_Moove" id="PropertyAvailability_error"></p>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4" id="propertyage">
              <div class="ui_kit_select_search add_new_property mb30">
                <select class="selectpicker show-tick" data-width="100%" id="PropertyAge" name="R_Pro_Age">
                  <option value="" disabled selected hidden>Age of property</option>
                  <option value='0-1 Years Old'>0-1 years</option>
                  <option value='1-5 Years Old'>1-5 years</option>
                  <option value='5-10 Years Old'>5-10 years</option>
                  <option value='10+ Years Old'>10+ years</option>
                </select>
                <p class="error R_Pro_Age" id="R_Pro_Age_error"></p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-12" id="passionby">
          <div class="new_property_form">
            <h4 class="title mb30">Possession by</h4>
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-md-4">
                <div class="ui_kit_select_search add_new_property mb30">
                  <select class="selectpicker show-tick" data-width="100%" id="possessionyear" name="R_possession">
                    <option value="" disabled selected hidden>Expected By</option>
                    <option value="wi3month">Within 3 Months</option>
                    <option value="wi6month">Within 6 Months</option>
                    <option value="by24">By 2024</option>
                    <option value="by25">By 2025</option>
                    <option value="by26">By 2026</option>
                    <option value="by27">By 2027</option>
                    <option value="by28">By 2028</option>
                    <option value="by29">By 2029</option>
                    <option value="by30">By 2030</option>
                  </select>
                  <p class="error R_possession" id="R_possession_error"></p>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="text-right">
          <!-- <a class="btn btn-thm listing_save_btn" href="#" type="submit" name="submit">Submit</a> -->
          <input class="btn btn-thm listing_save_btn" type="submit" name="Submit" value="Save">
        </div>
</form>
```

Comment: I made you a snippet. Perhaps take more care to use punctuation, I did my best to rewrite your description but we really want a [mcve] and easier to follow descriptions

Comment: You need to cut down your example and ask ONE question at a time. Like "How to toggle form elements"

Comment: i am asking one question

Comment: And what is that? It is not clear or I would not have thought you asked more than one

Comment: I am clearly mentioned what i want please check my description and my images i want custom required error message each and every field and i already design js code but my form have some logical part it means one field.

Comment: Sorry. I had to EXTENSIVELY rewrite your description to even be able to read it. So REMOVE all the parts that WORK and make a [mcve] of the part that does NOT work and THEN we can help you

Comment: i already mentioned which part not working residential part ready move field not working

Comment: Good luck. I am off.